# How to create a custom ruleprofile javascript sonarlint CLI

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarlint

I'm trying to create a custom rule profile for running a specific rule scan on directory.

I want to run a console log check in all js files.

I have defined a following property in environment variables.
export -DSonar_PROFILE=D:\testProfile.json

### testProfile.json

{"name":"Sonar way","ruleKeys":["ConsoleLoggingCheck","S2228"]}

When I run sonarlint command line tool. It is scanning all rules.
am I missing any thing here. any pointers will be helpful.

Following is the log when I run sonarlint CLI

D:\test\bin>sonarlint.bat
D:\test\test\bin..
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
INFO: Java 1.7.0_80 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Windows 7 6.1 amd64
INFO: SONARLINT_OPTS=-DSonar_PROFILE=D:\testProfile.json
INFO: Index files
INFO: 7 files indexed
INFO: 7 source files to be analyzed
INFO: 7/7 source files have been analyzed
INFO:

-------------  SonarLint Report  -------------

```
      12 issues (7 files analyzed)

      4 blocker
      3 critical
      5 major
```

---

INFO: SonarLint HTML Report generated: D:\GScanOjetRules\Runnable 
Jar\test\test\bin.sonarlint\

INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS

INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

INFO: Total time: 2.233s

INFO: Final Memory: 8M/118M

Answer (score 0):

There are two things going on here:

1. That's just not the way to specify a profile at analysis time. You can only use profiles that have been *defined on the server*. You would then set `-Dsonar.profile=[profile name]`. You cannot point this analysis property to a file. Well, not and get the results you want.
2. You can only apply a non-default profile in SonarLint:

   1. in Connected Mode - meaning you've associated the project on your localhost with its analog on the SonarQube server
   2. if the project on the SonarQube server is tied to that non-default profile